# Exracting specific patterns using regex

Tags: python, regex

I have something like this,

```
tr|F2EF46|F2EF46_HORVD  210753
sp|K7W3E0|K7W3E0_MAIZE  21032
```

I need to print in a separate file only ID's inside | |,

```
F2EF46
K7W3E0
```

This script finds the pattern, but how to print only the ID's?

```
import re
o=open('result.txt','w')
with open('input.txt','rb') as f:
    for line in f:
        if re.findall(r'([a-z][a-z])(\|[a-z0-9]*.*)\|', line):
            line = line.strip()
            line = line.rstrip()
            line = re.sub('(\|[a-z0-9]*.*)\|', '', line) 
            line = re.sub('\|', '', line)
            query_id = line
            f.write(query_id+'\n')
            o.write(line)
```

Comment: why not use `split()` instead? Something like `line.split('|')[1]` will give you the IDs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need regular expressions here:

```
id = line.split('|')[1])
```

Although if you really want to use regexes then you could do:

```
id = re.search('(\|)(.*?)(\|)', line).group(2)
```

Only don't use `id` as a variable name, it is a built-in function and you are overriding it.

Comment: I was using regex cause I have a file in csv format, with lines, some containing ID's some do not,some empty, so I wanted to find the specific patterns in the whole file but print only the ID's inside || brackets..

Comment: @user3224522 Does my answer solve your problem? See my edit, it should work now.

Answer (score 1):

If you still want to use regex, use [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
(?<=\|)[^|]+(?=\|)
```

[**Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/pE9zG8)